# rails 3.1 on Heroku - Javascripts are not cached

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, thin

I have deployed a Rails application on Heroku (web-server thin).

When I push it, I can see that the assets are properly precompiled
(Running: rake assets:precompile)

However, when I go to the my app site, and I browse between two pages with the same precompiled header

```
<head>
<-- ... other stuffs ... -->  
  <script src="/assets/application-5452d0cdbf85c04748c35fac325cd1d7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
```

I can see (Chrome confirmed it [note: disable cache is set to :no on the developer tools] and Safari & Firefox same slowness) that the file is reloaded.

Heroku logs are confirming it

```
Heroku logs
2011-11-03T11:03:08+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /assets/application-5452d0cdbf85c04748c35fac325cd1d7.js?_=1320318188543] miss
```

From browsing on several website, it seems the for static content the setting need to be done at the level webserver, and on the ruby docs it is explained how to do for apache (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html).

```
It’s the responsibility of the web server you use to set the far-future expiration date on cache assets that you need to take advantage of this feature.
```

Any experience with thin and how to configure the expiry on the js assets?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After two days of research, I found out what was wrong.

The "responsible" is jquery and the way it handle Ajax calls

> jQuery.ajax()
>
> cacheBoolean Default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp' If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser. Setting cache to false also appends a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL.

Adding the following code fixed my issue

```
<script>
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true});
</script>
```

Then the browser is able to reload it properly (I can see in the developer tool for that specific javascript : Size (from cache) - Time: 11ms).
Furthermore, the way rails is signing the precompiled assets will allow me to have them properly reloaded if I'll make a modification on the javascript (tested as well, the included in the header changed from

```
<script src="/assets/application-158fadc43ade74e58a8087ec8b95e760.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="/assets/application-5452d0cdbf85c04748c35fac325cd1d7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is exactly the behaviour I was expecting and looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There's no varnish cache on the Heroku cedar stack which historically cached static assets for you, so Rack Cache or similar might be interesting to you.

However, Rails should be setting headers on assets telling your browser to cache them forever, leaving that to handle the caching.

Comment: Thait is precisely what I am trying to achieve. Cedar is precompiling the js script for me (with a nice hashed extension so I am sure that if I modified it, the former one will be invalid), but then on the HTTP request, a ?_=1320318188543 (variable) is added, making the browser unable to use the cached version. Is this a further settings on Rails to remove this further version of the js or in the webserver?